# Checking variety of a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

I'm trying to check a vector in matlab. As example a vector has 3 different possibilites 0 1 and 2. Now i want to check how many of 0s 1s and 2s there are inside of this vector within matlab, so i can determine the best split choice for my decision tree. Maybe there is any easier way to do it?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `vector == some_num`, you return a binary array of locations of `some_num` in vector. With `vector(binary_array)` you return a subset of the array, indicated by '1's in `binary_array`.

Putting that together:

```
vec = [ 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2];
num_0 = length(vec(vec==0)); % = 2
num_1 = length(vec(vec==1)); % = 3

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i was lost a little but that's what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Although I like Brendan's answer, I prefer the following code.

```
array = [1 2 1 0 3 1 1 4];
num_1 = numel( find(array==1) );
```

`find` gives you the indices of the values. You can also use `~=`, `<` and `>`.

I suggest you adapt this to a function.